# Linux serial communication with unusual port names

Tags: mono, serial-port, uart

I'm trying to do some simple stuff with serial ports in Linux. Specifically:

> Platform - BeagleBone Black
>
> OS - Angstrom Linux
>
> Mono version 2.10.8.1 (Arm)

The board implements it's six serial ports as ttyO0 through ttyO5 instead of ttyS0.

It actually has ttyS0 through ttyS3.

When I enumerate the ports it finds the ttyS0 etc but not the ttyO0 etc. Unfortunately it is the ttyO0 etc ports that actually have the real serial ports. Is there any way to make Mono able to use these?

Thanks!

Phil

Comment: Having *real* serial ports is pretty rare on commodity hardware, they are usually emulated to use USB.  But your Beagleboard has both.  So it is actually ttyS0 that's the real serial port and you actually want to use the emulated one, the one that uses the FTDI chip.  You'll need a way to tell your program about that.  Use a configuration parameter is the normal way to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks, but the emulated port is ttyUSB0. The real ports are ttyO0 through ttyO5. There is no FTDI chip at all on a BeagleBone Black.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself.

Simple really. They are specifically scanning for port names starting with /dev/ttyS:

```
public static string [] GetPortNames ()
        {
                int p = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
                List<string> serial_ports = new List<string>();

                // Are we on Unix?
                if (p == 4 || p == 128 || p == 6) {
                        string[] ttys = Directory.GetFiles("/dev/", "tty*");
                        foreach (string dev in ttys) {
                                if (dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyS") || dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyUSB"))
                                        serial_ports.Add(dev);
```